# set time period to restart a container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

how would you do to restart the container service every 60 seconds I tried sleep but it doesn't work for me:

```
spark:
    image: jaegertracing/spark-dependencies
    environment:
      - STORAGE=elasticsearch
      - ES_NODES=http://localhost:9200
    command: [ /bin/bash -c sleep 20 ]
    restart: always
    networks:
      - elastic-jaeger
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use healthchecks combined with `restart: always`

```
healthcheck:
  test: curl -sS http://127.0.0.1 || exit 1
  interval: 5s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
```

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088261/restarting-an-unhealthy-docker-container-based-on-healthcheck
- https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/docker-health-check/

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming, the test will always return "1"; as in failure? What if there is an actual web service at 127.0.0.1?

Comment: What kind of answer is this? I already have a healthcheck on a container, that doesn't restart the container.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a very elegant solution here:

https://gist.github.com/kizzx2/782b500a81ce46b889903b1f80353f21

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports: ["80:80"]
    restart: unless-stopped

  restarter:
    image: docker
    volumes: ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 86400; docker restart app_app_1; done"]
    restart: unless-stopped
```